# How to avoid overlap view in relative layout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, textview, android-relativelayout

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView3"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView4"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView5"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView6"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView7"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView8"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView9" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="商店圖片:"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/imageView1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView10"
        android:contentDescription="@string/top" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

```
Simple output:
textview1     textview9
textview2     imageview1
.
.
.
button1
```

The above layout is a page that divide horizitonally, for the left side , there is a list of textview and button , for the right side, there is an image view. The problem is: when the textview content is too long, the imageview will overlap the content of it, besides using bringtofront(), are there any way (in xml ) to resize the width of the text view if it overlap with image view?

Comment: Why don't you try putting `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` to `ImageView` and `android:layout_alignLeft="@id/textView1"`. Then put `android:layout_below="@id/button1` to `textView10`.

Comment: What's the general idea, you need all the `TextViews` one below the other and at the end a `Button` (left column) and only one `ImageView` to the right (right column)?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you are using this kind of design than you should use linear Layout.
and use Table Rows in it to display this kind of view.

and also use weight so that your view doesn't et overlap on other views. try like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<TableRow 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="10">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="test"
        android:layout_weight="5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        android:textSize="20sp" 
        android:text="test"
        android:layout_weight="5"/>
</TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: As far as i know, if you are using layout_weight attribute, one of your dimensions(layout_height or layout_width) should be set to 0dp.

Comment: Yup..dats right, But here we didn't needed to set weight.it was just one property that i have showed. If we really want to set weight than we need to set 0dp either height or width.

Comment: Hey @ArmaanStranger can you please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49952965/recyclerview-horizontal-scrolling-to-left?noredirect=1#comment87836903_49952965

Answer (score 102):

Use layout_toStartOf in the first item with second item +id under double quotes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/selectaccount"
        android:text="very long text which used to overlap over radio button"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/selectaccount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

note this argument in textview

```
android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/selectaccount"
```

An XML is read from top to bottom

so this is how the Layout is rendered in Android

- android:layout_toStartOf="**@id/item** means that **item** is defined **above** this line
- android:layout_toStartOf="**@+id/item** means that **item** will appear later somewhere **below** this line

Comment: +1 for "@+id/item means that item will appear later somewhere below this line.  I never knew you could do that.  I always reordered my Views in the xml.  Thank you!

Comment: In case anyone's confused by the wording, +id denotes declaration of a new ID, it's not specifically related to things being "above" or "below". It's just like declaring a variable before you use it in code. The first time you want to use an ID, you have to declare it.

Answer (score 6):

Align the all the textviews to leftOf imageview like lastone : 
`android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imageView1"`

Comment: Ya all textview should be left align of imageview so that none of these textview will overlap the image

Comment: @HarishGodara he meant you have to use `layout_toLeftOf` rather than `layout_alignLeft`. I've updated your answer to the correct code.

Answer (score 2):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="1.0" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and tried pretty much everything suggested here and in other similar threads.

The one additional thing that did it for me was to add:

```
android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/youroverlappeditem"
```

so the overlapping item will only run up to the overlapped item.

`layout_toLeftOf` was not enough on its own

and of course `ellipsize="end"` was needed as appropriate.

Mine was for a `recyclerview` with a relative layout.

Answer (score 1):

You can overcome that issue by clicking on "infer constraints". Follow the picture which will show the way:

[image: HowTo AndroidStudio]

Answer (score 1):

Try [constraint layout](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiczb7fxYffAhUJi6wKHeABB6MQFjAAegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw0G1cYfJVImvuJ4GaVfjb-_). It simplifies your layout.

Answer (score -3):

Add this line one your xml layout

tools:ignore="RelativeOverlap"

Comment: That doesn't help at all. Things in the "tools" namespace only affect what you see in the Android Studio visual preview, not what happens in the app running on a device.